# How can I print the stringvalues of a Map in Dart in a for loop

Tags: loops, dart, dictionary

When I go through the map with the for loop I want to print out the corresponding items. How can I address them?

```
var manuMap = {3 : "hello", 5 : "greetings", 4 : "good buy"};
    for (var item in manuMap.keys) {
        print(item.runtimeType);
        print(item);
        //... print hello, greetings ...
    }
    print(manuMap[0]); does not work
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps

Answer (score 0):

**You can use map iteration**

```
Map manuMap = {3 : "hello", 5 : "greetings", 4 : "good buy"};
manuMap.forEach((key, value) { 
  print("key $key value $value");
});
```

// also you can use **map[key]=value;** as follow

```
print("key ${manuMap[3]}");//output "hello"
print("key ${manuMap[5]}");//output "greetings"
print("key ${manuMap[4]}");//output"good buy"
```